# How to refresh request token with microservice multiple instances

Tags: java, microservices, access-token, spring-cloud

**Scenario:**

When the request token expires and multiple requests happen from different service instances, that all request a new request token via the remote HTTP call, at the same time, the latter request token will make the former request token invalid. Because each request to get a new token will make the previous one invalid. The service to generate request token is a third party one, we can't change it.

**Questions:**

1. Our application architecture is microservice based, each service will have multiple instances, how can I reuse the request token between each service?(maybe store it in an external Redis is an option)
2. During the service starting up, how can we make sure only one refresh token request sent to the third party service?
3. Afterwards, when the request token expires, how can we renew it?

**Tech Stack:**

- Java 8
- SpringCloud
- Redis
- Rancher
- MySQL

Comment: Is each of your service validating the token with the third party token provider? Also is it the same identity that is being used through out for authentication?

Comment: A1: it's one service(say BookingService), but we have multiple instances of BookingService running at the same time. A2: yes.

Comment: Tokens are not likely to be validated by the authentication server for every service in your api flow. You have a means (public key) of verifying the token. Having said that if you want to make the calls in your scenario you do need one service that can manage the auth request for you. You can run this on a single machine. If multiple instance of booking service do come, they will make multiple calls to token service, which will only make one service to your third party service and then cache the token unless it expires. Or look into distributed locks if you don't want to write a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is an option that you can consider

1. Create a new MicroService for Token Management. All MicroServices will access the third Party Auth Component through this Service
2. In the Token Management Service, you create a Spring Singleton bean which would be automatically initialized when this services starts (@Autowired)
3. Inside this bean, you can have the logic for invoking the third party API
4. Based on your requirement, you can decide if a caching Service like Redis/memcache is needed or a RDBMS table would do
5. In this token Management service, when you get the token expired response from the third party API, you can have logic for renewing the token

Comment: This option still can't resolve the issue that multiple instances starting up at the same time. Each instance could be a singleton, but I will have multiple instances.

Comment: This can be achieved by persisting the token in the RDBMS table. When the service starts up, it refers to this table to check if the token exists. This  way you can achieve single token amongst all instances